# How to enable Unity related syntax highlighting with VSCode?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode, not VisualStudio for Unity scripting. VSCode has syntax highlighting for C#, which works fine, but all the Unity related stuff like `Vector3` doesn't get any highlights. I know, that you can change somehow the files, but I can't even find the C# folder in my extensions folder (There is everything else like cpp, css etc. just no c#). Would be great if someone could lead me to the folder location and how to add keywords for the highlighting.

Here is a screenshot, where you can see that `float` is highlighted, but `Transform` not.

[image]

Comment: Is it related to this? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133862/no-intellisense-with-with-unity-5-5-visual-studio-code-integration-osx-10-12-1

Comment: Is this a one-off thing or does it happen with all of your projects?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the latest VSCode and have it configured for Unity development...
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Does Intellisense work for Unity classes?  If yes, and you are just not seeing syntax colors, try a different theme.  (Preferences->Color Theme)

Some of them highlight class names and some don't.

Comment: Yeah Intellisense is working and I tried all the themes, but still no highlighting for variables like Transform or Vector3 and so on, I just added a screenshot. Is this working in your case?

Comment: @TobiasW - The colorization seems to be missing from the VSCode demo page, as well. (The main gif at the top of the page.)  [Page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity), [gif](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/other/unity/wow.gif)