# No intellisense with with Unity 5.5, Visual Studio Code integration, OSX 10.12.1

Tags: unity, visual-studio-code

I get this with the listed software. It doesn't recognize object types and I can't use reference-finding. I have the Omnisharp plugin installed and updated. Just wondering if this is supposed to work properly yet. I'm opening it with Assets->Open Project In Code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .csproj file, there's this:

```
<Reference Include="UnityEngine">
  <HintPath>/Applications/Unity 5.5.0f3/Unity.app/Contents/Managed/UnityEngine.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Note the space in the file path. Changing Unity's location to

`/Applications/Unity5.5.0f3`

then deleting the generated `.sln` and `.csproj` files fixed it.