# Why are Visual Studio and VSCode not giving me a dropdown list of methods and options etc?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode but I have also tried Visual Studio 2019 to write code for Unity, but when I'm writing the lines I don't get dropdown menus with for example the methods this class holds. Or objects. Or it's properties. etc.: basically, IntelliSense is not working.

Is there a setting that I need to enable in order to get those? Since I've seen everyone who use VSCode and visual studio get these dropdown menus.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119737/how-to-enable-unity-related-syntax-highlighting-with-vscode)?

Comment: I did but I didn't find anything to help my case

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I have had to do to solve this issue before:

- Make sure you have Visual Studio Code set as your editor in the unity preferences.
- Make sure you have the C# Visual Studio Code extension installed.
- Check the VSCode OmniSharp logs for any errors.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: everything is as it should be, C# extension is installed and enabled, I didnt find any errors from OmniSharp and VScode is the default IDE for Unity scripts. I reloaded and restarted VScode and still no changes.